# How to remove some indexes from a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

How can I replace certain values in df, column class that have "Np" value with index values in order to do some treatment.
df

```
    class      Project 
  0  A1         Math
  1  A2         Physics
  2  Np         Music
  3  A3         Danse
  4  Np         Acting
```

So i used

```
df['class'] = df['class'].where(df['class'] != 'Np', df.index.to_series())
```

and i got what i wanted

```
df
  class  Project
0    A1     Math
1    A2  Physics
2     2    Music
3    A3    Danse
4     4   Acting
```

Then I want to remove the index and keep the field empty after i finish df analysis.
Final output:

```
class  Project
0    A1     Math
1    A2  Physics
2         Music
3    A3    Danse
4        Acting
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your initial test as a mask and reuse it later:

```
mask = df['class'] == 'Np'
df['class'] = df['class'].where(~mask, df.index.to_series())

# processing goes here

df['class'] = df['class'].where(~mask, '')
```

output:

```
   class    Project
0   A1      Math
1   A2      Physics
2           Music
3   A3      Danse
4           Acting
```